# Yahoo! Contacts API fails for new users

Tags: oauth, yahoo, yql

I have spent the last several days implementing OAuth-based communication with Yahoo! in order to retrieve a user's contact information and I have successfully built an implementation which works beautifully with a Yahoo! account I created several years ago.

Now I am attempting to retrieve the contacts for a user I just barely created and Yahoo! is returning an incredibly informative 503 (Service unavailable) error to the tune of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<error xmlns="http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/schema.rng" xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:uri="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/errors/503" yahoo:lang="en-US">
  <description>Not available</description>
  <detail>new user</detail>
</error>
```

Currently, I am using the older version of the Contacts API which is queried with a request to: `http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/{guid}/contacts?format=XML`, so in an effort to track the issue I tested a query to the new YQL based mechanism in the [YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) and was able to retrieve contacts for the user in question. I attempted to switch my application to use YQL, but for some reason, reusing the OAuth authorization process I had in place for the old API is resulting in a 401 (Unauthorized) error when I request `http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/yql?format=xml&q=select%20*%20from%20social.contacts%20where%20guid={guid}` (or `guid=me`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<yahoo:error xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:uri="http://yahoo.com" xml:lang="en-US">
  <yahoo:description>Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem=&quot;OST_OAUTH_SIGNATURE_INVALID_ERROR&quot;, realm=&quot;yahooapis.com&quot;</yahoo:description>
  <yahoo:detail>Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem=&quot;OST_OAUTH_SIGNATURE_INVALID_ERROR&quot;, realm=&quot;yahooapis.com&quot;</yahoo:detail>
</yahoo:error>
```

So, I have two questions and I'd be happy with an answer to either one:

1. Why can't I get contacts from the Yahoo! old Contacts API for new Yahoo! accounts
2. (OR) Why is my YQL query for contacts returning a 401 error?

---

*Update*

I did some further testing with the original Contacts API and it seems that Yahoo! is blocking the retrieval of contacts for users which were created recently. Although I am not sure what Yahoo! considers 'recent', I was able to retrieve contacts for a user created a little over 2 weeks ago. Why isn't this in their documentation? :(